# Execute a command in the re-verse order of ids present in a file

Tags: awk

I am running the following command using awk on file.txt ,currently its running the command on the ids present in file.txt from top to bottom..i want the commmand to be run in the reverse order for the ids present in file.txt..any inputs on how we can do this?

```
git command $(awk '{print $1}' file.txt)

file.txt contains.

97a65fd1d1b3b8055edef75e060738fed8b31d3 
fb8df67ceff40b4fc078ced31110d7a42e407f16
 a0631ce8a9a10391ac4dc377cd79d1adf1f3f3e2 

.....
```

Comment: Do you want to run the file in reverse, or sorted top to bottom?  Reverse as in 2e3f3f1fda... or top to bottom as in item 9, item 8, item 7, item 6, etc

Comment: run in reverse....order should be a0631ce8a9a10391ac4dc377cd79d1adf1f3f3e2 ,fb8df67ceff40b4fc078ced31110d7a42e407f16,97a65fd1d1b3b8055edef75e060738fed8b31d3 ..

Comment: Are you bound to using awk or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: @AtlasWegman - other solutions are also fine,need to run on a linux box

Comment: Okay, posted a nice simple one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't bound to using `awk` then `tail` with the `-r` (for reverse) argument will do the trick...

myFile.txt

```
97a65fd1d1b3b8055edef75e060738fed8b31d3 
fb8df67ceff40b4fc078ced31110d7a42e407f16
a0631ce8a9a10391ac4dc377cd79d1adf1f3f3e2
```

Now to print it in reverse...

```
$ tail -r myFile.txt

a0631ce8a9a10391ac4dc377cd79d1adf1f3f3e2
fb8df67ceff40b4fc078ced31110d7a42e407f16
97a65fd1d1b3b8055edef75e060738fed8b31d3
```

---

EDIT:
To output this to a file simply redirect it out...

```
$ tail -r myFile.txt > newFile.txt
```

---

EDIT:
Want to write to the same file?  No problem!

```
tail -r myFile.txt > temp.txt; cat temp.txt > myFile.txt; rm temp.txt;
```

For some reason when I redirected `tail -r` to the same file it came back blank, this workaround avoids that issue by writing to a temporary "buffer" file.

Comment: is this actually going to update the file or jsut print on the console

Comment: just print to the console, but to update the file all you have to do is pipe it out

Answer (score 1):

To reverse the lines in a file using awk, use

```
awk '{a[i++]=$0} END {for (j=i-1; j>=0;) print a[j--] }' file
```

use `$1` instead of `$0` above to operate on the first field only instead of the whole line.